variable ownership in rust
I'm new rust language. I tried to understand the concept of ownership and borrow.
let mut s = String::from("hello");
{
    s.push_str(" world");
    let mut r1 = &mut s;
    println!("{}",s);
}

let mut s = String::from("hello");
{
    s.push_str(" world");
    let mut r1 = &mut s;
    println!("{}",r1);
}

if I executed the code, it didn't show any error.
But if I added another one print statement of variable 'r1' or 's' it show error. Couldn't get why its show the error
let mut s = String::from("hello");
{
    s.push_str(" world");
    let mut r1 = &mut s;
    println!("{}",s);
    println!("{}",r1);
}

Error message:
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `s` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> /tmp/3uevECWJtw/main.rs:9:19
   |
8  |     let r1 = &mut s;
   |              ------ mutable borrow occurs here
9  |     println!("{}",s);
   |                   ^ immutable borrow occurs here
10 |     println!("{}",r1);
   |                   -- mutable borrow later used here
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::format_args_nl` which comes from the expansion of the macro `println` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

Please help me to understand this.

The rust book has an almost identical example. Check out this paragraph: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#mutable-references

If you replace the print statements, it works. The problem was that you can't borrow s var as an immutable while it is being borrowed by r1 var as mutable.
// ** this compiles **
//println!("{}",s);
println!("{}",r1);
println!("{}",s);

